# DB2 migrating database from V9.5 aix to V10.1 linux

Tags: linux, db2, database-migration, aix, db2-luw

We have a few DB2 V9.5 databases (largest around 100GB) on AIX and need to migrate them to an existing V10.1 instance that's on Linux.
Due to endianness diff between aix and linux a simple backup and restore isn't working.
I had to use db2look and db2move utilities to extract/export, FTP and LOAD which is time consuming and needs a longer downtime.
Is there a simpler way of doing this?
Namely bypassing the endianness issue or scripting to export and load multiple tables at once?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to finesse the endianness issue.

db2look + db2move is probably the most straightforward way to do it. You could perhaps set up your old database as a federated source for the new database and LOAD FROM CURSOR directly from your old tables. This lets you skip the ftp step (and having to manage staging space on both systems). See here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0901fechner/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When linking to a webpage in an answer, it is best practice to quote the necessary information on the page in case the link goes bad.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to complete this type of operation and I did it by creating the database schema with db2look then moving the data with the load from cursor operation.
Now you don't need to bother with federation, you can use the database option on the declare cursor statement.

This example is from the DB2 Information Centre:

DECLARE mycurs CURSOR DATABASE dbsource USER dsciaraf USING mypasswd 
FOR SELECT TWO,ONE,THREE FROM abc.table1 
LOAD FROM mycurs OF cursor INSERT INTO abc.table2

The link to the page is:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/c0005437.html